# DynamicalODEProblem not compatible with EnsembleProblem?

Tags: julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I'm trying to use the `EnsembleProblem` feature, where in my case `prob` is a `DynamicalODEProblem(f1, f2, v0, u0, tspan)`. I'd like my ensemble to span different initial conditions for the same ODE.

Example 1 in [this tutorial](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/features/ensemble/) explains how to establish an ensemble with a general `ODEProblem`. For a `DynamicalODEProblem`, though, I can't find a way to specify `prob_func` without getting a compilation error. The issue that I get is that there doesn't seem to find a compatible overload of `remake` that does the trick. My initial attempt was

```
function prob_func(prob, i, repeat)                                                               
   remake(prob, v0[i], u0[i])                    
end
```

but compiler complains that this isn't compatible with the two supported overloads

```
remake(::SciMLBase.ODEProblem; f, u0, tspan, p, kwargs, _kwargs...)
```

and

```
remake(::Any; kwargs...)
```

I also tried wrapping `v0` and `u0` using an `ArrayPartition`, but it didn't work either.

In short: how can I define an `EnsembleProblem` where `prob` is a `DynamicalODEProblem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: simply write the `kwarg` for `u0` explicitly when using `ArrayPartition`:

```
function prob_func(prob, i, repeat)                                                               
   remake(prob, u0=ArrayPartition(v0[i], u0[i]))                    
end
```